# NodeJs and Jest: Mock Mongoose multiple calls find().sort().limit()

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs, mocking

Wondering how to mock **multiple chained mongoose calls in jest**. For example I have a simple method:

```
exports.Limit5Videos = async() => {
try{
    const mostClicked = await Videos.find().sort({ clicks: -1 }).limit(5);
    return mostClicked;
}catch(err){
    return err;
}
};
```

This method returns the top 5 most clicked videos "on a website". I'm trying to unit test this method but when I do i keep getting the following:

TypeError: Videos.find(...).sort(...).limit is not a function when I run my test.

Here is my test:

```
var video1 = new Video();
video1.clicks = 1;
var video2 = new Video();
video2.clicks = 2;
var video3 = new Video();
video3.clicks = 3;
var video4 = new Video();
video4.clicks = 4;
var video5 = new Video();
video5.clicks = 5;
var video6 = new Video();
video6.clicks = 6;

var listOfVideos = [video1, video2, video3, video4, video5, video6];
var expected = [video6, video5, video4, video3, video2];
var mockedValue = listOfVideos.filter(v => v.clicks > 1).sort(function compare(a, b) {
    return b.clicks - a.clicks;
  });
  
  
Video.find = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ sort: 
jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockedValue)})); 
await expect(videoHelper.GetMostClickedLimit5()).resolves.toBe(expected);
```

---

How can I write a jest unit test for this method? Sorry if this is basic but new to jest and can't find anything out there on multiple chained calls. I can run the test using "sort" but can't figure out how to add "limit".

Comment: I would suggest you *don't*. You can mock Limit5Videos from the perspective of the rest of your app, it's a sensible facade, but you shouldn't mock an interface you don't own (you'd have to make a very complicated mock, for one thing).

Comment: I am facing with same issue. Can anyone know how to resolve this?